# Section break properties is changed unexpectedly after merging document using altChunk

Tags: openxml

When merging documents using the AltChunk feature in OpenXml, the section break properties and page setup defined in a section break is changed, such as orient and pageMargin. Any idea to fix this problem? It confuses me for a few days. T.T

And this is my coding:

```
AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId); // Note: Id is generated by Guid.New method

using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
}
var altChunk = new AltChunk();
altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
altChunk.AppendChild(
    new AltChunkProperties(
        new MatchSource() { Val = new OnOffValue(true) }
    ));
```

And I have asked ChatGPT and it answer me that 'This is because AltChunk merges the content of the documents at the document level, rather than at the section level.', but I cannot find any official document.